# Frozen connection using ssh over Amazon EC2 and MySQL-workbench over Amazon RDS

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I'm using the following amazon services:

- Ec2 with Ubuntu 10.04
- RDS with MySQL 5.5.27-log

I'm using kubuntu 11.10 in my machine. The problems are the following (I don't know if they have relation):

1. When I connect with my server EC2 over ssh, if I don't use the shell in 3-5 minutes, the ssh is frozen, lock. I can't do nothing, I can't type, I can't logout. I have to kill the ssh and open a new session.

   1. When I connect to my MySQL DB over Amazon RDS, my client is blocked/frozen/zombie on 5 minutes of inactivity or when I execute 5-10 selects.

I use to connect to MySQL MySQL-workbench and MySQL-client. I have the same problem.

Please, anyone know how do I solve these?

Comment: i am connected all day long with Amazon Linux AMI with putty and a secure ppk file fyi

Comment: I hope I will can too :(